# Faster computation?

Tags: performance-tuning

I have this code

```
f[x_, n_] := Sum[ComplexExpand@Abs[Sin[x + k]], {k, 0, n}]
Table[Minimize[{f[x, n], -Pi <= x <= Pi}, x], {n, 5}] // TableForm
```

It works but the computation time is so big. There is an easy modification of the code to achieve the same result faster?

Comment: Try to remove the `SetDelay`. use `=` not `:=`

Comment: Depending on your goals, you could also omit `ComplexExpand` and use `NMinimize` instead.